# How to get ClickListener of left and right button in main app using MaterialCalendarView

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, android-studio-2.3, google-calendar-api

I am using MaterialCalendarView Library and i added in my application for customization and I require Left and right button controll and controll left to right or right to left scroll in MainActivity but did not resoved please give me any suggestion if you know about it.
here is my code my java code.

```
mcv.state().edit()
                    .setFirstDayOfWeek(day_name)
                    .setMinimumDate(CalendarDay.from(2016, 1, 3))
                    .setMaximumDate(CalendarDay.from(2017, 12, 25))
                    .setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.WEEKS)
                    .commit();
```

here is my XML code

```
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
        app:mcv_selectionColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
```

here is Library Link where i get this [MaterialCalendarView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a callBackinterface in library and added method in that interface and and implement in MaterialCalendarView class that class is in library and other in main app respected class and pass controll to that app class when position chnage on scroll base and its work for me here is final code for more understanding

CallBackInterface

```
public interface CallBackInterface {

    void sendResponse(int position,CalendarDay calendarDay);
}
```

Respected class where you want scroll controll access

```
 mcv.setCallBackInterfacecustom(new CallBackInterface() {
                @Override
                public void sendResponse(int position, CalendarDay calendarDay) {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, calendarDay.getDate()+"" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

MaterialCalendarView class that is basically library class I added that library as a module in application code and here is code and link of that class [MaterialcalendarView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/MaterialCalendarView.java)

here is code

added a method in that class that is...

```
 public void setCallBackInterfacecustom(CallBackInterface _callBackInterfacecustom) {
       callBackInterfacecustom = _callBackInterfacecustom;
   }
```

I set setResponse method in viewpager that is ...

```
      @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                titleChanger.setPreviousMonth(currentMonth);
                currentMonth = adapter.getItem(position);
                Log.e("page scrolled",""+position+"month"+currentMonth);

                CallBackInterface _CallBackInterface = callBackInterfacecustom;
                if (_CallBackInterface != null) {
                    _CallBackInterface.sendResponse(position,currentMonth);
                }
}
```

Hope so it will others who want.